# Java expressions and removing everything after DOT with eval

Tags: java

I tried the following code but it seems that i have a little problem here.

By using the code above, i get results like

```
C:\temp>java -jar test.jar
2.0
6.0

C:\temp>
```

How can i have only "2" and "6" instead the ones i get? Thanks again!

Comment: Ha!  Welcome to JavaScript.  There are no Integers.  There is only Number.  Further, all Numbers are, essentially, floats (or doubles, I can't remember...I just know there are not any ints). You want to get rid of the decimal points?  You're going to need either convert these kids to int or some up with some NumberFormat that doesn't show the decimal place.

Comment: @BobKuhar thank you! I tried to convert to INT or take what's until indexOf(".") but with no luck... could you please give me an example? I'm out of ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"js"` script engine does no conversion: it treats every number as `double`s.

That way, you'll have to format those `results` objects (as they are `double`s). One possible approach is to use the [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");  
    String[] array = {"-1+3", "10-4"};

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); 

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {            
        Object results = engine.eval(array[i]);
        System.out.println(df.format(results));
    }
}
```

[Output (online demo)](http://ideone.com/SBLVIl):

```
2
6
```

Comment: This is it! This is the answer! Stack says i can accept the answer in 3 minutes since you posted it... can i do something to actually accept it?

Comment: Hmm.. I think all you can do is wait a bit, then the option to accept will be available.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no Integers, only Numbers and Numbers are Floats.  The code below leverages Java's Formatter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to declare that the output should have no decimal places.  If you want to convert this to int, you can leverage the fact that Number has intValue() method.

If you are stuck in JavaScript, you owe it to yourself to read Crockford's "JavaScript, the Good Parts".  He covers the JavaScript edge-cases pretty well:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class JavaScriptEval {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName( "js" );
        String[] array = { "-1+3", "10-4" };

        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            try {
                Object results = engine.eval( array[i] );
                // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html
                String resultsAsString = String.format( "%.0f", results );
                // Naked cast can get you in trouble
                int resultsAsint = ( (Number) results ).intValue();
                System.out.println( "results_as_string: " + resultsAsString + ", results_as_int: " + resultsAsint );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```